# Entender funcionamiento "funcion"

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
    function f(a, b, c, d) {
        b = 2.0
        c = 'D'
        return !(!d && (b > 3.0 || a >=5))
        }

var d, c, a, x;


      a = false
      c = 4.0
      d = 5
      x = f(d, c, 'X', a)

console.log(x)
```

El tema es que no acabo de entender porque el resultado de "x" es false.

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: La función devuelve la negación de algún argumento, por lo tanto devolverá un valor truthy o falsey, según el argumento negado se evalúe a `false` o `true` en dicho contexto booleano.

Comment: SI, pero el funcionamiento con el codigo qeu tengo no logro entenderlo

Answer (score 7):

La función recibe 4 argumentos o parámetros, sin embargo, internamente siempre reescribe 2 de ellos, por lo tanto debemos sólo tomar en cuenta los que no son reescritos como argumentos variables dentro de la función.

En cada ejecución, los valores de `b` y `c` son siempre los mismos dentro de la función. Luego se retorna simplemente una evaluación en un contexto booleano de una serie de comparaciones y operaciones de cortocircuito.

De la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos) se tiene:

> los operadores `&&` y `||` regresan en realidad el valor de uno de los operandos especificados, por lo que si estos operadores se usan con valores no Boolean, posiblemente regresen un valor no Boolean.

Tomando esto en cuenta, debemos analizar lo que se encuentra a la derecha de la sentencia `return`

```
!(!d && (b > 3.0 || a >=5))
```

Lo primero a notar es que tenemos un [operador lógico de negación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logico), por lo cual, se aplicará la negación del valor devuelto por la expresión encerrada entre paréntesis.

Dentro del paréntesis más externo tenemos:

```
!d && (b > 3.0 || a >=5)
```

En donde tenemos el primer [operador lógico de cortocircuito](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos#Evaluaci%C3%B3n_contra_corto_circuitos) `&&`.

En Javascript existen valores considerados [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy) y [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), y se refiere al valor booleano (`true` o `false`) que tomará una variable cuando se le evalúa en un contexto booleano. Por lo tanto, al aplicar la negación a `d`, se está evaluando `d` en un contexto booleano.

```
!d // <- devuelve false si y sólo si su valor es distinto de un valor falsy
```

Ahora, como el `!d` es falso, ya que `d` es un valor `truthy` (`d` vale `false` dentro de la función, según el código mostrado en la pregunta), el operador de cortocircuito (`&&`) devolverá el operador de la derecha: `(b > 3.0 || a >=5)`.

Veamos un ejemplo de este operador funcionando:

```js
let d = false
let valor = !d && 'Esto es una cadena';
console.log(valor); // <- muestra 'Esto es una cadena'
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como podemos ver, el operador de cortocircuito siempre devuelve uno de los operandos, basados en si su valor es verdadero o falso al momento de realizar su evaluación. Para el caso de `&&` se devuelve el primer operando si el mismo evalúa a `false`. Pero si el primero operando evalúa a `true` devuelve el segundo operando, esto es lo que sucede actualmente con este código.

Ahora que ya sabemos que se devuelve el segundo operando, podemos decir que esto:

```
!(!d && (b > 3.0 || a >=5))
```

es equivalente a esto otro:

```
!(b > 3.0 || a >=5)
```

cuando `d` es `falsy`.

Ahora debemos analizar el código anterior, nuevamente interviene un operador de cortocircuito cuyos operandos son sentencias de comparación.

Para el operador `||`, el valor devuelto será el primer operando si el mismo evalúa a `true`. Y será el segundo operando si el primer valor evalúa a `false`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let op1 = false;
let op2 = 'Una cadena';
let valor = op1 || op2;
console.log(valor);
valor = op2 || op1;
console.log(valor);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top:0;
}
```

Con esto presente, lo único que queda por definir es qué valores tomarán los operandos:

```
b > 3.0
a >= 5
```

Según la definición de la función, el valor de `b` siempre es establecido a `2.0`, por lo tanto el primer operando devuelve `false`.

Así, el operador de cortocircuito `||` devolverá como resultado el segundo operando: `a >= 5`. Y como el valor de `a` es 5, entonces, el resultado será `true`.

Resumiendo, dada la expresión inicial:

```
!(!d && (b > 3.0 || a >=5))
```

La misma es equivalente a:

```
!(b > 3.0 || a >=5)
```

Dado que `d` es `false`, luego, el resultado es:

```
!(a >= 5)
```

Ya que `b > 3.0` es `false`.

Y como `a >=5` es `true`, la negación de `true` es `false` y de allí el resultado obtenido.

**Nota:**

Debemos notar, que si bien las variables `a, c, d` declaradas fuera de la función tienen unos valores establecidos antes de ser llamada la función, son pasadas en las posiciones correspondientes a los argumentos `a, b, d` de la función, esto hace confuso leer a primera vista los valores correspondientes a cada variable dentro de la función.

En este caso, se declara fuera de la función `a = false`, pero su valor dentro de la función se corresponde con `d`, ya que es la posición en la que fue pasada.

Lo mismo para `c` que es declarada con un valor de `4.0` fuera de la función, pero es pasada como argumento a la misma en la posición de `b`.

Por último `d` toma un valor de 5 fuera de la función, pero es pasado como argumento en la posición de `a` dentro de la función.

Esto se conoce como [alcance o contexto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Scope) de las variables.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function f(a, b, c, d) {
  console.log(`Soy 'a' y mi valor es: ${a}`);
  console.log(`Soy 'b' y mi valor es: ${b}`);
  console.log(`Soy 'c' y mi valor es: ${c}`);
}

var a, b, c;

a = 'A';
b = 'B';
c = 'C';

f(c, a, b);
```

Espero que esto te ayude a entender el código de la función y el porqué devuelve ese resultado.

Comment: Brutal esta respuesta, mis respetos amigo, yo la entiendo, pero se nota el esfuerzo y la calidad de esta respuesta, obviamente tienes mi punto arriba.

Comment: Me uno al comentario anterior. ¡Excelente explicación de operadores de cortocircuito!

Answer (score 0):

Simplificando: (doy por supuesto que conoces los operadores lógicos)

Dentro la funcion d=true, b=4.0

Si reemplazamos el `return` por los valores queda así:

```
return !(true && (4.0>3.0 || ...) )
```

Y como 4.0>3.0 = true tenemos...

```
return !(true && ( true || da_igual_porque_true||x_da_true) )
```

Así que `!(true&&true) = !true = false`

Y por eso retorna un `false`.

Comment: Tienes un error, dices: *Y como 3.0>4.0 = true tenemos...*, lo cierto es que `3.0>4.0` devuelve `false`. Saludos

Comment: Cierto, pique mal la tecla.