# ¿Cómo resuelvo esta operación return?

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando con JS y me han propuesto el siguiente acertijo:

```
function f(a, b, c, d){
    b = 4.0;
    c = 'A';
    return !(d || (a > 4) && (b < 3.5));
}

var d, c, a, x;

a = true;
c = 7.0;
d = 5;
x = f(d,c,'R',a);
```

Se me pide que de el resultado final de la variable `x` al llamar la función, que resulta 'false'.
Pero, ¿alguien me explica qué está ocurriendo exactamente en la operación de retorno?

```
return !(d || (a > 4) && (b < 3.5));
```

Comment: Puedes ir mostrando los resultados de las operaciones intermedias con `console.log()`, F12, Consola, así lo verás más claro

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No entendes nada de esa instruccion o entendes que hace y no porque se transforma en false?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Entender funcionamiento "funcion"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404724/entender-funcionamiento-funcion)

Comment: @MauricioContreras dios mío muchísimas gracias